# Retrieve return values from multiple DIV's as one object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component `Home` that calls `Property` component with two different types of data as shown given below.

```
<Property
          location={this.props.fetchLocation}
          area={this.props.area}
        />
```

`Property` component renders both of the data sets as nested lists and in different `div's`. I am using a third component to display elements in the form of checklist and I am calling it from `Property` component as:

```
<div><ul>{this.props.location.map(item => {
        return(
        <div><Filter {...item} onChange={this.handleChange}/></div>);
      })}</ul></div>
```

and a same `div` for the second data set. 
I am able to get the checked list item in `handleChange`:

```
handleChange(name, checked) {
    console.log(`This ${name} is ${checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}`)
  }
```

I am wondering if it's possible to pack checked values from both `div's` i.e both lists into one object and send to `Home` component in order to filter the search results afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can do it is by maintaining a state in the Home component and then updating it from child whenever a value is checked or unChecked

Home

```
state: {
   selectedLocations: [],
   selectedAreas: []
}

updateCheckedValues = (key, value, isChecked) => {
   this.setState((prevState) => {
       if(isChecked) {
          return {[key]: prevState[key].concat(value)}
       } else {
          return { [key]: prevState[key].filter(obj => obj !== value)}
       }
   })
}

    <Property
          updateCheckedValues={(key, value, isChecked) => {this.updateCheckedValues(key, value, isChecked)}}
          location={this.props.fetchLocation}
          area={this.props.area}
        />
```

Child:

```
<div><ul>{this.props.location.map(item => {
    return(
    <div><Filter {...item} onChange={this.handleChange}/></div>);
  })}</ul></div>

handleChange = (key, name, checked) => {
   this.props.updateCheckedValues(key, name, checked);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Shubham Khatri. I am new to React. Can you please explain how the checks in `updateCheckedValues` are doing just to make it clear for me?

Comment: So the selected values are stored as an array, and when you uncheck them, we need to delete those values from the array, thats why those checks are there